How to properly use .bbappend file in Yocto to change menuconfig settings for certain recipe?
I'm trying to include swupdate package in my target image using Yocto and meta-swupdate.
For swupdate there is a menuconfig available, where I can specify the configuration.
But, as stated here by Stefano Babic, the proper way is to use swupdate_%.bbappend file and use menuconfig only for finding options available and their naming. In my case I want to enable systemd feature for swupdate. As stated in previous link, that option has to be disabled in menuconfig (otherwise the bitbake command fails), and I should enable it by .bbappend file. Following that advice I have created folders structure:
swupdate
└── swupdate_%.bbappend
└── swupdate/
    └── systemd.cfg


With .bbappend file content:
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://systemd.cfg"


And systemd.cfg content:
CONFIG_SYSTEMD=y
When I bitbake my project, with above included, and systemd manually disabled in menuconfig, then it works fine, and I can see swupdate status on my target device:

And now the part I don't understand:
The systemd option is disabled by default for meta-swupdate (which I checked in defconfig file found in tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/swupdate/2024.05-r0).
But once I have built my target image with that .bbappend included, for each next build I have to manually check in menuconfig if that systemd option is disabled, because sometimes (I don't understand when) it gets automatically enabled, and build fails.
Even when I clean swupdate with
bitbake -c cleanall swupdate
and as far as I understand everything should go back to default for swupdate,
I need to again manually disable systemd in menuconfig.
I would be grateful for explanation why this is happening

In bitbake, behaviour that appears only some of the time is often caused by missing dependencies. What you wrote seems the correct way to me, but it could be caused by other things in your setup. The cleanall is not a clean way to reset all in bitbake (ironic I know). Try to remove your tmp folder or clone the repo again and rebuild. See if the issue persists

Hello @Mo_, thanks for you suggestion! I tried it out, but unfortunalety it did not work, the problem stays the same

Check your layer priority with bitbake-layers show-layers(Increase your layer priority) and check if other layer has swupdate.bbappend file with bitbake-layers show-appends swupdate
